# Jinja - Convert element to string and call JS function

Tags: javascript, python, jinja2

I am creating a web application using *Python*, *Flask* and *Jinja*.

**What works:**

From the Python side I have a list `my_list = ["Rome", "Milan", "Bari", "Naples"]` which is used to populate through Jinja the HTML template page rendered to the client with the content of interest.

```
<ul>
   {% for n in my_list %}
   <button>{{n}}</button>
   {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Resulting in:

```
<button>Rome</button>
<button>Milan</button>
<button>Bari</button>
<button>Naples</button>
```

[image]

**What does not work:**

I now want to trigger a JS function that should output to console the received string `parameter` (e.g "Rome", "Milan", "Bari", "Naples" that now represents the names contained by the various buttons)

```
<script>
    function foo(parameter) {
         console.log(parameter);
    }
</script>
```

and in order to do this I modify the Jinja template part like the following:

```
<ul>
    {% for n in my_list %}
    <button onclick="foo({{n}})">{{n}}</button>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

The problem is that, when I press a button (e.g Rome) I receive in the JS console the following error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Rome is not defined

Of course I am able to understand that this is happening *because Rome is not defined and Rome is not a string* (which is what I need it to be in order to correctly make the function call).

So my question is how do you convert `Rome` into `"Rome"`?

I am interested in understanding how to convert Jinja elements to the `string` datatype.

I am not too much familiar with Jinja, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `onclick="foo('{{n}}')"`

Comment: @helb you made my day with just a pair of '' :D. I love StackOverflow, thank you. Consider to place yours an answer this way I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jinja renders the string variables without any surrounding quotes. So:

```
<button onclick="foo({{n}})">{{n}}</button>
```

becomes

```
<button onclick="foo(Rome)">Rome</button>
```

…which obviously makes the JS engine look for a variable called `Rome`.

Just put your own quotes around it to make it a string in JS:

```
<button onclick="foo('{{n}}')">{{n}}</button>
```

→

```
<button onclick="foo('Rome')">Rome</button>
```